# How can I set Firebase Database Security Rules for Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm making android app which will collect useful info from user. Here is the code

```
Firebase postRef = mRef.child("marks");
Map<String, String> marks = new HashMap<String, String>();
marks.put("Name", fname);
marks.put("Phone", fphone);
marks.put("Year", fyear);
marks.put("Email", femail);
String uid=postRef.getKey();
Toast.makeText(im.this,"Thanks!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This will result in getting the data from every user of my Android App. How should I set specific rules by which only authenticated users can get access of their information. Not other users info.

I tried this in Firebase Rules:

```
{
  "rules":{
  "$uid":{
    ".read":"auth.uid==$uid",
    ".write":"auth.uid==$uid",
    ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['uid','Email','Name'])"
    }
  }

}
```

But its not working. Kindly tell me specific solution.

Comment: The rules look fine to ensure that users can only access their own data. The code you shared doesn't read from or write to the database, so can't be failing. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks alot Frank for looking up! In actual database, there is no UID fied. Here is the logcat.
'09-21 00:36:03.971 31112-31223/com.example.amey.ilsalpha V/RenderScript: 0x559eaba9c0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 6
09-21 00:36:04.413 31112-31465/com.example.amey.ilsalpha W/RepoOperation: setValue at /marks/-KS7zP1oKI0WmcikjO1G failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied'

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question and comment correctly you are putting your data under the "marks" node. That means you also have to include that in your security rules like this:

```
{
"rules":{
  "marks":{
    "$uid":{
      ".read":"auth.uid==$uid",
      ".write":"auth.uid==$uid",
      ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['uid','Email','Name'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre! But still its not working! Though It helped alot for read. But need solution for write.

Comment: @coolamz You should add the code you are using to write to your question.

Comment: My apologies! Its first question here! Here is the current code:
{
"rules":{
  "marks":{
    "$uid":{
      ".read":"auth.uid==$uid",
      ".write":true,
      ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['Email','Name'])"
      }
    }
  }
}